# Unexpected value returned outside loop after loop finished running

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  /* ... */
}
console.log(i);

//expect 9 as loop states i < 10, however it shows 10
```

I would expect when `i` is logged that it would show a value of 9. From what I understand is that the loop will run from 0-9 and then will stop as the loop states that `i < 10`. However, when I `console.log(i)` it shows `10`. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Try re-writing this as a `while` loop and you'll see what is happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The increment happens *before* the last check.

In other words, the loop ends if and only if `i >= 10`, so it follows that after the loop ends, `i` must be at least 10.

The loop happens like this:

1. Set `var i = 0;`
2. Check if `i < 10` (true), execute loop.
3. Execute `i++`.
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 until `i < 10` is false (in this case, until `i = 10`).

Comment: Lovely, perfect explanation

Answer (score 1):

What you have,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    /* ... */
}
console.log(i); // logs 10
```

Can be re-written as a `while`

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    /* ... */
    i++;
}
console.log(i); // logs 10
```

And now we see that at the end of `i === 9` there is one last increment made so `i === 10`, causing the condition to fail thus exiting the loop.

Comment: also, a good explanation. Thanks Paul. Fairly basic stuff, but never noticed it so explicitly before. Good to understand it perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Because the loop exits when it *is not less than 10.*  i.e. when `i == 10`

The order of operation of the following for loop:

```
for(a;b;c) {
    d;
}
```

Is this:

```
A, repeat(b, d, c) while b==true
```

Where the last statement called is `b`.  This means that the statement just before `b` is `c`

Comment: Your _"is this"_ looks like a `do..while` and not a `while`. Just write it as a regular `while`

Comment: Correct.  But I was trying to write it in more English-type semantics, rather than code.  I had originally written "A, B, D, C, B, D, C, B" but that didn't really get the idea across the way I wanted either.

Answer (score 0):

That loops runs until i = 10, then stops.  You are then console logging the 10.